# Access ZF2 module service from non-Zend application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am building a Zend application with a number of modules. I would like to reuse some of these modules within other projects which are not using the Zend Framework.

I have used included the init_autoloader.php in a non-Zend test script and can access the Zend Framework classes as expected.

I can also set up my autoloader to load classes from my module directly.

What I'm aiming to do is to load the module and access its services from its Module class from the getServiceConfig() function.

Using ModuleManager, I have set up DefaultListeners and can load the module.

```
use Zend\ModuleManager\Listener;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;

chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
// Instantiate and configure the default listener aggregate
$listenerOptions = new Listener\ListenerOptions(array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor'
    )
));
$defaultListeners = new Listener\DefaultListenerAggregate($listenerOptions);
// Instantiate the module manager
$moduleManager = new ModuleManager(array(
    'Group',
));
// Attach the default listener aggregate and load the modules
$moduleManager->getEventManager()->attachAggregate($defaultListeners);
$moduleManager->loadModules();
```

What I would like to do is instantiate an instance of ServiceManager and be able to get the services from the module as I can within the application.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create just the service manager like so:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

/* Insert your code to setup whatever autoloader you want */

$configuration = include 'config/application.config.php';

$serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
$serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $configuration);

$serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
```

If you want to only use a specific module(s) then create a copy of your `config/application.config.php` that will only include the module(s) you want. Note, you can just place the config array directly into `$configuration` in the code above rather than including a file if you desire.